# Finding the last index of the first substring found in a string

Tags: c++, string, find, substring

I was looking through a lot of the solutions on here and there doesn't seem to be anything that does this with a built-in c++ method.

```cpp
std::string str = "Hey I'm John, John's friend";
int substrindex = str.find("John"); // Finds the index of "J" from the first "John"
// But what If I wanted to find the end of the substring of str "n" using a built-in method like find?
```

Comment: Add the length of `"John"` to the returned index.

Comment: Your question is unclear.   Do you wish to find the index of `'n'` in the first occurrence of `"John"`, or in the last occurrence of `"John"`.    The solutions are different between those cases, but hardly difficult - but, if you can't describe your requirement clearly, you can't expect to be able to meet it either.

Comment: @Peter title does contain _"...first substring found in a string_" which I think is clear enough.

Comment: I want to find the last index `"n"` of the first substring, so the first `"John"`

Comment: @RichardCritten I need to have it so I can find the last index without knowing how long the substring is

Comment: Why? The length will already be used internally in `find`

Comment: If you have the index to the `J`, what do you think you need to do to get the index of the `o`? From that, what do you think you need to do to get the index of the `n`?

Comment: And you *always* know the length of the substring you search for, because you know the actual substring itself (otherwise how could you search for it)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Lol good point, my brain is intelligent

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want the last index for a **specific** word in a givin string, then you can do it like this

```
std::string str = "Hey I'm John,John's 
friend";
std:: string word="John";
int index=str.find(word)+word.size()-1;
std::cout<<index;
```

if you mean something else, you should clarify more.